# how to retrieve view url

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, javascript

with the newest sharepoint online updates it no longer works to simply type in the Url of a document like such:

```
www.yoursite.sharepoint.com/site/site1/documentLibraryName/folder/documentName.docType
```

Instead, you have to use the view URL to put said document into a page viewer or iframe. If i were to put the above URL into an iframe or the URL bar, it would try to download the document, not load the viewer. Thus the only way I can figure this out to work is by clicking the ellipsis on a document, the "get a link" and using the "view url" in the iframe. In which case, it ends up looking like such (note I loaded each file in a content editor with a script using an iframe):
[image]

I would like to make a sharepoint designer workflow that adds a document view URL to a list so that I may use a javascript script on said list to pull the URLs for multiple documents and display each in an iframe. The list looks like this (I am pulling 5 different documents based on the parameter- projectName- passed to the page):

[image]

The URLs should come from the document library which has 5 content types, for each of the 5 documents types to pull.
[image]

So my thought was to have this be two parts:
1) a workflow to copy document's view URLs into projectParameters based on their content type and associated project
2) Run 5 content editors, each that pull one of the document types based on the passed parameter.

How can I set up the workflow such that it will add the 5 view URLs to the list projectParameters?

edit: solution for those interested:
here is the workflow:
[image]

here is the javascript(1 of 5, just changed the columns in the query):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

        function retrieveListItems() {
            //retrieve the document library's name
            var parameter = GetUrlKeyValue('ProjectName'); //get the parameter name, tested and it works

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); //create client context at this site collection.
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ProjectParameters'); //create list object by the title of the, projectParameters is the list to look through
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); //create CAMLquery to pull in list items.
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'LinkTitle\'/>' + 
            '<Value Type=\'Computed\'>' + parameter + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>' + 
            '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'); //define the query, here we pull in the field where the parameter matches. 
            this.collListitem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);//get the items from the list object based on the query defined above.

            clientContext.load(collListitem);//telling the object model to prepare to execute the following object by loading it into the client context.

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  


        }
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var ProjectCharter = '';
            //var ActionPlan = '';
            //var MonthlyReport = '';
            //var ProjectSchedule = '';
            //var Budget = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListitem.getEnumerator();

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                ProjectCharter += oListItem.get_item('Project_x0020_Charter');
                //ActionPlan += oListItem.get_item('Action_x0020_Plan');
                //MonthlyReport += oListItem.get_item('Monthly_x0020_Report');
                //ProjectSchedule += oListItem.get_item('Project_x0020_Schedule');
                //Budget += oListItem.get_item('Project_x0020_Budget');
            };
            var docUrl= ProjectCharter;//set the doclibname to the pulled field

            modIframe(docUrl);
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function modIframe(DocumentLibraryUrl){
            document.getElementById('doclibView').src=DocumentLibraryUrl;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src='' height=600 width=900 id='doclibView'>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: I haven't been working with SP Online so not answering as a proper answer, but is this "view URL" something that can be accessed as a property of either the file itself or the file's list item when retrieved via REST?  You could conceivably make a REST call from the workflow to get the current item (or the current item's file) and get the "view URL" from that.

Comment: hmm ill look into it, haven't done a ton with REST yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [this blogpost](http://paulryan.com.au/2013/link-to-open-in-browser-with-owa/) and basically put this data in the column you want:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]&action=default
```

Comment: you're the best! that is exactly what I was looking for. A+, gold star for you